# Is Powershell able to take a webpage and click on specified areas?

Tags: powershell

Edited to clarify early questions:

I am new to the field of programming, and I'm focusing on PowerShell at the moment since my employer uses it. I am trying to write a Powershell script that will go to a government webpage. On this webpage, there is a list of miscellaneous information that I can do multiple things with. I can Create View, E-mail a Link, Edit list, Export to Excel, etc. I am trying to get Powershell to open this page, and click on the Export to Excel option, and possibly open the Excel spreadsheet.

I have only learned the basics of the basics of Powershell and the only function I've been able to find is that involves webpages is Invoke-WebRequest. I can Invoke-WebRequest the webpage, but I get an error since Powershell can't log in. I have found resources here that logged into a webpage, and then "click" something, but Powershell doesn't understand how to login for the webpage since it automatically logs in when you open the page, and doesn't recognize click as an actual thing it can do. Finally, I don't know how to identify the Export to Excel option on the webpage so that I can actually click it.

I do not know what direction to take for a script. If there are any resources or suggestions you could give me, I would appreciate it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: "[...] that will end up in an Excel Spreadsheet" - how do you render a button click in Excel? What would that look like?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why does it have to be Powershell? Why couldn't you use Cypress.io or Puppeteer or even Power Automate?

Comment: For robust web-browser _UI automation_ you need a _web-testing framework_, such as [Selenium WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/) e.g. in combination with the [Microsoft Edge WebDriver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium). Selenium has a .NET (C#) library, which is in principle usable from PowerShell. The [third-party `selenium-powershell` module](https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell) aims to be a PowerShell-friendly wrapper around it, but it is currently looking for maintainers and may therefore be _obsolescent_.

Comment: I've updated my question to better reflect what I'm trying to ask for, and remove some unimportant information that was confusing. Ending up in an Excel Spreadsheet was just the result of the thing I wanted clicked, and was unnecessary to mention. It has to be PowerShell because that is what is accepted where I work.

Comment: There's nothing built into PowerShell that allows you to simulate interacting with a web browser (within limits, in _Windows PowerShell_ you _used to_ be able to it via the DOM returned from `Invoke-WebRequest` provided by the long-obsolete Internet Explorer). Nowadays, `Invoke-WebRequest` and `Invoke-RestMethod`, when targeting HTML pages, only return their _static_ content - no JavaScript required for dynamically populating pages is run. There are only two basic options: find a _web service_ that returns the data of interest, or use browser UI automation, as described in my previous comment.

Comment: You can use the HtmlAgilityPack inside a Powershell application.  Powershell is written in Net Library and any Net method can be used in PS.  It is the DOM method that mklement0 is referring to the is removed from a WebRequest.  It is also what you are probably using in the Excel spreadsheet so code should be very similar to you Excel code.  See https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PowerHTML/0.1.6

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure the comments regarding the UI modules are better paths to look into, but my usual approach for these kind of specific projects is to scrape my way through.

[Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is an invaluable tool for that - it'll let you inspect the requests/responses to replicate the ones you need. First you'll need to authenticate to the site, then you can access those restricted pages.

**Authentication**

1. Start by clearing your cookies (you'll have to login again)
2. Launch Fiddler and enable [decrypting https trafffic](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/decrypthttps)
3. Using your browser, open the website's login page
4. Find the entry in Fiddler - it'll start with a GET request to the url you provided; this is the 1st bit to replicate in powershell:
5. Enter your login details and hit login/submit on the site. You'll note the corresponding POST entry in Fiddler. Depending on the site, there's various levels of response data that need to be sent back - use the fiddler entry as a guide.

Here's an example script for a simple page:

```
# Get initial page forms and start our session.
$loginpage = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $url -Method GET -SessionVariable session

# Fiddler showed that Form data was being sent with these details.
$loginpage.Forms['Login'].Fields.username = $username
$loginpage.Forms['Login'].Fields.password = $password

# Replicate whatever the login POST entry was in Fiddler
$checkauth = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.website.com/login' -WebSession $Session -Body $res.Forms['Login'].Fields -Method POST -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

It's not unusual for a site to also require you to set specific header entries; you can use the `-header` flag and a simple hashtable:

```
$headers = @{"Referer"="https://website.com/login"; "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"=1}
```

6. View your powershell invoke requests going out via Fiddler - confirm you're sending the same required data in the same field as the original browser requests. There's a lot of additional data you won't need to include, so start with what looks obvious to include and keep expanding if you don't get the expected response. For example, the `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests` header might need to be set for the POST to be accepted.

Once you get a success response to your login, use the same WebSession variable to access restricted pages. Use Fiddler once again to see the request the browser sends when you click 'download' on the file you're wanting, then replicate.

If you hit errors with the last step after you're authenticated, it's likely because some sites just like to be difficult. Sometimes there'll be specific referrers you need to reference on restricted pages, or a csrf token passed in the body or header, etc. For these, it's still the same process as above of just using Fiddler to work out what info your browser is sending that you need to replicate.